# How do I get PyAudio to compile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, pyaudio, portaudio

I installed PyAudio and imported it in my program but, when I complied it I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Documents/Python/MicForAudio.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 101
    print "Please build and install the PortAudio Python " +\
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.
```

I tried all I know and still don't know how to fix it. There's not  print "Please build and install the PortAudio Python " +\ on line 101. It's invisible.

Comment: python 3 ==>  `print()`

Comment: Your package doesn’t support python 3. See the “File” line of the traceback, it’s saying that the source code of pyaudio caused the error

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am late, but PyAudio should work now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).